# addressDictionary returns random nil

Tags: ios, swift, locationmanager

I've used [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32832601/3314336) for my App. Its works great but sometime crashes, after `+/- 50` secondes of tracking my route. I know it has something to do with the optionals "?", but I can't get it to work.

I get the following message:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional

Part where the code breaks:

```
 if let locationName = placeMark.addressDictionary?["Name"] as? NSString
      {
         print(locationName)
         self.locationName = locationName as String
      }
```

Full locationManager code:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    for location in locations as [CLLocation] {
        let howRecent = location.timestamp.timeIntervalSinceNow

        //start motion tracker
        motionTracker()

        //location name tracker
        let locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate
        let latitude: CLLocationDegrees = locValue.latitude
        let longitude: CLLocationDegrees = locValue.longitude
        let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
        let location = CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
        geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location)
            {
                (placemarks, error) -> Void in

                let placeArray = placemarks as [CLPlacemark]!

                // Place details
                var placeMark: CLPlacemark!
                placeMark = placeArray?[0]

                // Address dictionary
                print(placeMark.addressDictionary)

                // Location name
                if let locationName = placeMark.addressDictionary?["Name"] as? NSString
                {
                    print(locationName)
                    self.locationName = locationName as String
                }

                // Street address
                if let street = placeMark.addressDictionary?["Thoroughfare"] as? NSString
                {
                    //print(street)
                    self.locationStreet = street as String                 
                }

                // City
                if let city = placeMark.addressDictionary?["City"] as? NSString
                {
                    self.locationCity = city as String
                    //print(city)
                }

                // Zip code
                if let zip = placeMark.addressDictionary?["ZIP"] as? NSString
                {
                    //print(zip)
                }

                // Country
                if let country = placeMark.addressDictionary?["Country"] as? NSString
                {
                    //print(country)
                }
        }
```

Comment: Immediately before that line, you `print(placeMark.addressDictionary)`. Just before it crashes, what does that print?

Comment: @JasperBryant-Greene:

it prints out: `Optional([SubLocality: Millbrae Meadows, SubAdministrativeArea: San Mateo, State: CA, Street: I-280 N, CountryCode: US, ZIP: 94030, Thoroughfare: I-280 N, Name: I-280 N, Country: United States, FormattedAddressLines: (
    "I-280 N",
    "Half Moon Bay, CA  94030",
    "United States"
), City: Half Moon Bay])
I-280 N
empty
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional` the empty is the motiontracker

Comment: The print line is crashing the next time around the loop, because `placeMark` is `nil` so `print(placeMark.addressDictionary)` fails. Google doesn’t have a reverse geocode for that location and is returning an empty array. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you’re hitting a case where Google doesn’t have a reverse geocode result for your location and is returning an empty array.

Instead of:

```
let placeArray = placemarks as [CLPlacemark]!
var placemark: CLPlacemark!
placemark = placeArray?[0]
```

… which assumes that there will be an array and it will always contain at least one element, use:

```
if let placemark = placemarks?.first {
    // Rest of your code
}
```

Comment: I updated the answer to handle the case that the geocoder doesn’t provide an array at all – it’s documented that `placemarks` can be nil if an error occurred: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CLGeocodeCompletionHandler