# Swift - Generate an Address Format from Reverse Geocoding

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-maps, reverse-geocoding

I am trying to generate a Formatted Full address using CLGeocoder in Swift 3. I referred to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32832601/4177142) thread to get the code given below.

However, sometimes the app crashes with a 'nil' error at the line:

```
//Address dictionary
print(placeMark.addressDictionary ?? "")
```

**Questions:**

1. How can I concatenate these values retrieved from the GeoCoder to form a full address? (Street + City + etc)
2. How do I handle the nil error I get when the func is unable to find an address?

**Full code:**

```
func getAddress() -> String {
        var address: String = ""

        let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
        let location = CLLocation(latitude: selectedLat, longitude: selectedLon)
        //selectedLat and selectedLon are double values set by the app in a previous process

        geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) -> Void in

            // Place details
            var placeMark: CLPlacemark!
            placeMark = placemarks?[0]

            // Address dictionary
            //print(placeMark.addressDictionary ?? "")

            // Location name
            if let locationName = placeMark.addressDictionary!["Name"] as? NSString {
                //print(locationName)
            }

            // Street address
            if let street = placeMark.addressDictionary!["Thoroughfare"] as? NSString {
                //print(street)
            }

            // City
            if let city = placeMark.addressDictionary!["City"] as? NSString {
                //print(city)
            }

            // Zip code
            if let zip = placeMark.addressDictionary!["ZIP"] as? NSString {
                //print(zip)
            }

            // Country
            if let country = placeMark.addressDictionary!["Country"] as? NSString {
                //print(country)
            }

        })

        return address;
    }
```

Comment: See my answer in swift 4.1 Xcode 9.4.1. You can get even village name details also. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16647996/get-location-name-from-latitude-longitude-in-ios/51797299#51797299

Comment: addressDictionary is deprecated in iOS 11 and onwards

Answer (score 91, accepted):

```
func getAddressFromLatLon(pdblLatitude: String, withLongitude pdblLongitude: String) {
        var center : CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D()
        let lat: Double = Double("\(pdblLatitude)")!
        //21.228124
        let lon: Double = Double("\(pdblLongitude)")!
        //72.833770
        let ceo: CLGeocoder = CLGeocoder()
        center.latitude = lat
        center.longitude = lon

        let loc: CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude:center.latitude, longitude: center.longitude)


        ceo.reverseGeocodeLocation(loc, completionHandler:
            {(placemarks, error) in
                if (error != nil)
                {
                    print("reverse geodcode fail: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                }
                let pm = placemarks! as [CLPlacemark]

                if pm.count > 0 {
                    let pm = placemarks![0]
                    print(pm.country)
                    print(pm.locality)
                    print(pm.subLocality)
                    print(pm.thoroughfare)
                    print(pm.postalCode)
                    print(pm.subThoroughfare)
                    var addressString : String = ""
                    if pm.subLocality != nil {
                        addressString = addressString + pm.subLocality! + ", "
                    }
                    if pm.thoroughfare != nil {
                        addressString = addressString + pm.thoroughfare! + ", "
                    }
                    if pm.locality != nil {
                        addressString = addressString + pm.locality! + ", "
                    }
                    if pm.country != nil {
                        addressString = addressString + pm.country! + ", "
                    }
                    if pm.postalCode != nil {
                        addressString = addressString + pm.postalCode! + " "
                    }


                    print(addressString)
              }
        })

    }
```

Comment: and last print addressstring . you got your whole address

Comment: There's an issue with this. The func goes through this process before waiting for the address to be processed from the LatLng. So therefore I end up with an empty string

Comment: @RickGrimesLikesWalkerSoup check my whole method that i use in my project . you can also use it

Comment: You are a beautiful human being. This works like a charm. Thanks dude!

Comment: @RickGrimesLikesWalkerSoup :)

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya: Works like a charm, Thanks a lot, but one thing to mention, you should not force unwrap **placemark**, cause it may be nil sometimes which happened with me, use a if let to get rid of unwanted crashes. :P Cheers. Happy Coding.

Comment: Add each address strings to an array and then use     
let addressString = addArray.joined(separator: ",") to convert into String

Comment: `let pm = placemarks! as [CLPlacemark]` gives me an error: "warning: could not execute support code to read Objective-C class data in the process"

Comment: let placemark = placemarks! as [CLPlacemark] this line error showing you right ? @grant

Comment: How to return address?? I am not able to return. Pls help

Answer (score 26):

Formatting addresses is hard because each country has its own format.

With a few lines of code, you can get the correct address format for each country and let Apple handle the differences.

Since iOS 11, you can get a Contacts framework address:

```
extension CLPlacemark {
    @available(iOS 11.0, *)
    open var postalAddress: CNPostalAddress? { get }
}
```

This extension is part of the `Contacts` framework.
This means, this feature is invisible to you in the `XCode` code completion until you do

```
import Contacts
```

With this additional import, you can do something like

```
CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location, preferredLocale: nil) { (clPlacemark: [CLPlacemark]?, error: Error?) in
    guard let place = clPlacemark?.first else {
        print("No placemark from Apple: \(String(describing: error))")
        return
    }

    let postalAddressFormatter = CNPostalAddressFormatter()
    postalAddressFormatter.style = .mailingAddress
    var addressString: String?
    if let postalAddress = place.postalAddress {
        addressString = postalAddressFormatter.string(from: postalAddress)
    }
}
```

and get the address formatted in the format for the country in the address.

The formatter even supports formatting as an attributedString.

Prior to iOS 11, you can convert `CLPlacemark` to `CNPostalAddress` yourself and still can use the country specific formatting of `CNPostalAddressFormatter`.

Comment: I like this approach but when I add your extension I'm seeing 'postalAddress' used within it's own type?

Comment: Do not add the extension. I'm showing the Extension that Apple added. Just remove it and everything should be fine.

Comment: oh haha, my bad.

Comment: Life saver. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @GerdCastan Is there a similar built-in function to help convert an `MKPointAnnotation` to a `CLPlacemark`? So far, all I can see is to create the addressDictionary myself....

Comment: @Zonker.in.Geneva the only usable information in ˚MKPointAnnotation˚ is the coordinate. So you create a CLLocation from the coordinates, then a CLPLacemark from your CLLocation.

Comment: Right, but creating a Placemark requires an addressDictionary. And I can’t figure out how to set the name of a Placemark. And I can’t decide if I should is MK- or CL-Placemarks

Comment: @Zonker.in.Geneva name and address dictionary are optional in the constructor. You can set them to nil.

Answer (score 8):

This is my code for swift 3

```
func getAdressName(coords: CLLocation) {

    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(coords) { (placemark, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("Hay un error")
            } else {

                let place = placemark! as [CLPlacemark]
                if place.count > 0 {
                    let place = placemark![0]
                    var adressString : String = ""
                    if place.thoroughfare != nil {
                        adressString = adressString + place.thoroughfare! + ", "
                    }
                    if place.subThoroughfare != nil {
                        adressString = adressString + place.subThoroughfare! + "\n"
                    }
                    if place.locality != nil {
                        adressString = adressString + place.locality! + " - "
                    }
                    if place.postalCode != nil {
                        adressString = adressString + place.postalCode! + "\n"
                    }
                    if place.subAdministrativeArea != nil {
                        adressString = adressString + place.subAdministrativeArea! + " - "
                    }
                    if place.country != nil {
                        adressString = adressString + place.country!
                    }

                    self.lblPlace.text = adressString
                }
            }
        }
  }
```

You can esaily call above funcation like:

```
let cityCoords = CLLocation(latitude: newLat, longitude: newLon)
cityData(coord: cityCoords)
```

Comment: let place = placemark! as [CLPlacemark] do not force unwrap it will crash whole app on no network

Answer (score 6):

1. For fixing the empty address issue, either you can use a class property to hold the appended value or you can use a closure to return the value back to the calling function
2. For fixing the crash you need to avoid the force unwrapping of optionals

Using a closure you can do it like:

```
// Using closure
func getAddress(handler: @escaping (String) -> Void)
{
    var address: String = ""
    let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
    let location = CLLocation(latitude: selectedLat, longitude: selectedLon)
    //selectedLat and selectedLon are double values set by the app in a previous process
    
    geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) -> Void in
        
        // Place details
        var placeMark: CLPlacemark?
        placeMark = placemarks?[0]
        
        // Address dictionary
        //print(placeMark.addressDictionary ?? "")
        
        // Location name
        if let locationName = placeMark?.addressDictionary?["Name"] as? String {
            address += locationName + ", "
        }
        
        // Street address
        if let street = placeMark?.addressDictionary?["Thoroughfare"] as? String {
            address += street + ", "
        }
        
        // City
        if let city = placeMark?.addressDictionary?["City"] as? String {
            address += city + ", "
        }
        
        // Zip code
        if let zip = placeMark?.addressDictionary?["ZIP"] as? String {
            address += zip + ", "
        }
        
        // Country
        if let country = placeMark?.addressDictionary?["Country"] as? String {
            address += country
        }
        
       // Passing address back
       handler(address)
    })
}
```

You can call the method like:

```
getAddress { (address) in
    print(address)
}
```

Comment: Gives error on this line.
geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) -> Void in
 
"Escaping closure captures non-escaping parameter 'handler'"

Comment: @Ashu In later swift versions you have to write `@escaping` for closures, updated the answer. Please have a look.

Answer (score 3):

To concatenate you can simply replace `return address` by this :

```
return "\(locationName), \(street), \(city), \(zip), \(country)"
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14721054)

Comment: @Mack This answer to the "how to concatenate..."

Comment: Probably you should add some more explanation about what to do, how to use, where to use this line & some thing. Now just simply placing 1 line doesn't always get proper solution.

Answer (score 2):

Keeping it simple - A full Swift 3 & 4 compatible View Controller example for obtaining a formatted address string from user's location (add in the other keys available in [CLPlacemark](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clplacemark) if you want more information in your string):

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

let manager = CLLocationManager()
let geocoder = CLGeocoder()

var locality = ""
var administrativeArea = ""
var country = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    manager.delegate = self
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    manager.startUpdatingLocation()

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let location = locations[0]
        manager.stopUpdatingLocation()

    geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) in
        if (error != nil) {
            print("Error in reverseGeocode")
            }

        let placemark = placemarks! as [CLPlacemark]
        if placemark.count > 0 {
            let placemark = placemarks![0]
            self.locality = placemark.locality!
            self.administrativeArea = placemark.administrativeArea!
            self.country = placemark.country!
        }
    })
}

func userLocationString() -> String {
    let userLocationString = "\(locality), \(administrativeArea), \(country)"
    return userLocationString
}

}
```

Calling print(userLocationString()) in this example will print: suburb, state, country

*Don't forget to add **Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description** to your Info.plist file beforehand, to allow the user to grant permissions to your app to utilise location services.*

Comment: what about the street address?

Comment: @Zonker.in.Geneva Check out the link in the explanation, more specifically 'thoroughfare'. In this example you would use placemark.subThoroughfare, placemark.thoroughfare, perhaps placemark.subLocality and placemark.postalCode https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clplacemark/1423814-thoroughfare

Answer (score 2):

Here's a 2-3 line version of the answers here:

```
    func getAddress(placemarks: [CLPlacemark]) -> String {
        guard let placemark = placemarks.first, !placemarks.isEmpty else {return ""}
        let outputString = [placemark.locality,
                            placemark.subLocality,
                            placemark.thoroughfare,
                            placemark.postalCode,
                            placemark.subThoroughfare,
                            placemark.country].compactMap{$0}.joined(separator: ", ")
        print(outputString)
        return outputString
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
func getAddress(from coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, completion: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
        let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
        let location = CLLocation.init(latitude: coordinate.latitude, longitude: coordinate.longitude)
        
        geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) -> Void in
            
            // check for errors
            guard let placeMarkArr = placemarks else {
                completion("")
                debugPrint(error ?? "")
                return
            }
            // check placemark data existence
            
            guard let placemark = placeMarkArr.first, !placeMarkArr.isEmpty else {
                completion("")
                return
            }
            // create address string
            
            let outputString = [placemark.locality,
                                placemark.subLocality,
                                placemark.thoroughfare,
                                placemark.postalCode,
                                placemark.subThoroughfare,
                                placemark.country].compactMap { $0 }.joined(separator: ", ")
            
            completion(outputString)
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(CLLocation(latitude: vehicleLocation.latitude, longitude: vehicleLocation.latitude), completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) -> Void in

  guard error == nil else {completionHandler(nil); return}

  guard let place = placemarks else {completionHandler(nil); return}

  if place.count > 0 {
    let pm = place[0]

    var addArray:[String] = []
    if let name = pm.name {
      addArray.append(name)
    }
    if let thoroughfare = pm.thoroughfare {
      addArray.append(thoroughfare)
    }
    if let subLocality = pm.subLocality {
      addArray.append(subLocality)
    }
    if let locality = pm.locality {
      addArray.append(locality)
    }
    if let subAdministrativeArea = pm.subAdministrativeArea {
      addArray.append(subAdministrativeArea)
    }
    if let administrativeArea = pm.administrativeArea {
      addArray.append(administrativeArea)
    }
    if let country = pm.country {
      addArray.append(country)
    }
    if let postalCode = pm.postalCode {
      addArray.append(postalCode)
    }

    let addressString = addArray.joined(separator: ",\n")

    print(addressString)

    completionHandler(addressString)
  }
  else { completionHandler(nil)}
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I create my own static class for Geocoding and get attributes of CLPlacemark and obtain a complete address, like "usually" returns Google:

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation

class ReverseGeocoding {

    static func geocode(latitude: Double, longitude: Double, completion: @escaping (CLPlacemark?, _ completeAddress: String?, Error?) -> ())  {
        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)) { placemarks, error in
            guard let placemark = placemarks?.first, error == nil else {
                completion(nil, nil, error)
                return
            }

            let completeAddress = getCompleteAddress(placemarks)

            completion(placemark, completeAddress, nil)
        }
    }

    static private func getCompleteAddress(_ placemarks: [CLPlacemark]?) -> String {
        guard let placemarks = placemarks else {
            return ""
        }

        let place = placemarks as [CLPlacemark]
        if place.count > 0 {
            let place = placemarks[0]
            var addressString : String = ""
            if place.thoroughfare != nil {
                addressString = addressString + place.thoroughfare! + ", "
            }
            if place.subThoroughfare != nil {
                addressString = addressString + place.subThoroughfare! + ", "
            }
            if place.locality != nil {
                addressString = addressString + place.locality! + ", "
            }
            if place.postalCode != nil {
                addressString = addressString + place.postalCode! + ", "
            }
            if place.subAdministrativeArea != nil {
                addressString = addressString + place.subAdministrativeArea! + ", "
            }
            if place.country != nil {
                addressString = addressString + place.country!
            } 

            return addressString
        }
        return ""
    }
}
```

Then the implementation:

```
    ReverseGeocoding.geocode(coordinate: coordinate, completion: { (placeMark, completeAddress, error) in

        if let placeMark = placeMark, let completeAddress = completeAddress {
            print(placeMark.postalCode)
            print(placeMark)
            print(completeAddress)
        } else {
            // do something with the error
        }
```

Finaly the print:

```
15172
Calle del Arenal, 4, Calle del Arenal, 4, 15172 Oleiros, A Coruña, España @ <+43.33190337,-8.37144380> +/- 100.00m, region CLCircularRegion (identifier:'<+43.33190337,-8.37144380> radius 70.84', center:<+43.33190337,-8.37144380>, radius:70.84m)
Calle del Arenal, 4, Oleiros, 15172, A Coruña, España
```

Answer (score 1):

```
func convertLatLongToAddress(latitude:Double, longitude:Double) {
    let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
    let location = CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
    var labelText = ""
    geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) -> Void in

        var placeMark: CLPlacemark!
        placeMark = placemarks?[0]

        if placeMark != nil {
            if let name = placeMark.name {
                labelText = name
            }
            if let subThoroughfare = placeMark.subThoroughfare {
                if (subThoroughfare != placeMark.name) && (labelText != subThoroughfare) {
                    labelText = (labelText != "") ? labelText + "," + subThoroughfare : subThoroughfare
                }
            }
            if let subLocality = placeMark.subLocality {
                if (subLocality != placeMark.subThoroughfare) && (labelText != subLocality) {
                    labelText = (labelText != "") ? labelText + "," + subLocality : subLocality
                }
            }
            if let street = placeMark.thoroughfare {
                if (street != placeMark.subLocality) && (labelText != street) {
                    labelText = (labelText != "") ? labelText + "," + street : street
                }
            }
            if let locality = placeMark.locality {
                if (locality != placeMark.thoroughfare) && (labelText != locality) {
                    labelText = (labelText != "") ? labelText + "," + locality : locality
                }
            }
            if let city = placeMark.subAdministrativeArea {
                if (city != placeMark.locality) && (labelText != city) {
                    labelText = (labelText != "") ? labelText + "," + city : city
                }
            }
            if let state = placeMark.postalAddress?.state {
                if (state != placeMark.subAdministrativeArea) && (labelText != state) {
                    labelText = (labelText != "") ? labelText + "," + state : state
                }

            }
            if let country = placeMark.country {
                labelText = (labelText != "") ? labelText + "," + country : country
            }
            // labelText gives you the address of the place
        }
    })
}
```

Here as an improvement I added place name as well. It makes address more meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

```
 func getAddressFromlatLong(lat: Double, long: Double, completion: @escaping (_ address: String) -> Void){
    let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: long)
    let geocoder = GMSGeocoder()
    var add = ""
    geocoder.reverseGeocodeCoordinate(coordinate) { (response, error) in
      if let address = response?.firstResult() {
        
        guard let arrAddress = address.lines else {return}
        if arrAddress.count > 1 {
            add =  /(arrAddress[0]) + ", " + /(arrAddress[1])
    
        }else if arrAddress.count == 1 {
            add =  /(arrAddress[0])
        }
        completion(add)
      }
    }
  }
```