# How to get the address from the coordinate

Tags: ios, swift, cllocation, cllocationcoordinate2d

I want to get the address from the coordinate. I have attached my code below..

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let lastLocation = locations.last!
    let latvalue     = lastLocation.coordinate.latitude
    let lngvalue     = lastLocation.coordinate.longitude
    self.db_latvalue = latvalue
    self.db_lngvalue = lngvalue
    let location = CLLocation(latitude: latvalue, longitude:lngvalue)
    let address = CLGeocoder.init()
    address.reverseGeocodeLocation(CLLocation.init(latitude: latvalue, longitude:lngvalue)) { (places, error) in
        if error == nil{
            if let place = places{
                   print("addressshowingssq \(place)")
                self.db_address = "\(place)"

            }
        }
    }
```

**Output:**

> [L-30 2nd A Main Road, L-30 2nd A Main Road, HSR Layout, Bengaluru,
>   Karnataka 560102, India @ <+12.91597974,+77.62879254> +/- 100.00m,
>   region CLCircularRegion (identifier:'<+12.91597974,+77.62879254>
>   radius 70.94', center:<+12.91597974,+77.62879254>, radius:70.94m)]

**I want only the address as i mention below**

> L-30 2nd A Main Road, L-30 2nd A Main Road, HSR Layout, Bengaluru,
>   Karnataka 560102

I researched google i got different solution so i got confused.

Comment: Please show the solutions you have tried to get the address part. Did you read the documentation for `CLPlacemark`? Your first place to go should always be the Apple documentation.

Comment: see this for help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41358423/swift-generate-an-address-format-from-reverse-geocoding

Comment: `place` is a `CLPlacemark` object, you might want to look at its property instead of using it fully. Like `place.address`?

Comment: `if let place = places{
                   print("addressshowingssq \(place)")
                self.db_address = "\(place)" this is the one i tried

            }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Update

I have done a few modification to `iVarun's` solution. This is simpler. and working.

First, add this function:

```
func geocode(latitude: Double, longitude: Double, completion: @escaping (CLPlacemark?, Error?) -> ())  {
    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)) { completion($0?.first, $1) }
}
```

After that,
    get the address:

```
geocode(latitude: latvalue, longitude: lngvalue) { placemark, error in
    guard let placemark = placemark, error == nil else { return }
    // you should always update your UI in the main thread
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        //  update UI here
        print("address1:", placemark.thoroughfare ?? "")
        print("address2:", placemark.subThoroughfare ?? "")
        print("city:",     placemark.locality ?? "")
        print("state:",    placemark.administrativeArea ?? "")
        print("zip code:", placemark.postalCode ?? "")
        print("country:",  placemark.country ?? "")
    }
}
```

Result:

```
address1: Rua Casuarina
address2: 443
city: Rio de Janeiro
state: RJ
zip code: 20975
country: Brazil
```

---

As @iOSer indicated, `CLPlacemark` is capable of giving you this part of the string, However.

You could split the string:

```
let output:String = "[L-30 2nd A Main Road, L-30 2nd A Main Road, HSR Layout, Bengaluru, Karnataka 560102, India @ <+12.91597974,+77.62879254> +/- 100.00m, region CLCircularRegion (identifier:'<+12.91597974,+77.62879254> radius 70.94', center:<+12.91597974,+77.62879254>, radius:70.94m)]"
let items = output.components(separatedBy: "@")
print(items[0])
```

Becuse the `@` will be **always** included, you could skip the rest.

Result: 
[image: R]

Comment: `@` as of `At` will be definitely included always if you use that as a output. try more locations and see if it has an `@` or not

Comment: What means `L-30`? Why do you want twice `L-30 A Main Road`? Also using `description` of an object (that's what is doing `"\(place)"`) that's NOT recommended as Apple could change it in next iOS version.

Comment: @Larme, as of now; it’s the way to go; also I provided two options

Comment: I disagree with that method. I'm not sure at all about that "Becuse the @ will be always included, you could skip the rest." too. Also, Apple could tomorrow reverse the order.

Answer (score 3):

Hope this will help you:

```
address.reverseGeocodeLocation(CLLocation.init(latitude: latvalue, longitude:lngvalue)) { (places, error) in
            if error == nil{
                let placeMark = places! as [CLPlacemark]

                if placeMark.count > 0 {
                    let placeMark = places![0]
                    var addressString : String = ""

                    if placeMark.subThoroughfare != nil {
                        addressString = addressString + placeMark.subThoroughfare! + ", "
                    }
                    if placeMark.thoroughfare != nil {
                        addressString = addressString + placeMark.thoroughfare! + ", "
                    }
                    if placeMark.subLocality != nil {
                        addressString = addressString + placeMark.subLocality! + ", "
                    }

                    if placeMark.locality != nil {
                        addressString = addressString + placeMark.locality! + ", "
                    }
                    if placeMark.administrativeArea != nil {
                        addressString = addressString + placeMark.administrativeArea! + ", "
                    }
                    if placeMark.country != nil {
                        addressString = addressString + placeMark.country! + ", "
                    }
                    if placeMark.postalCode != nil {
                        addressString = addressString + placeMark.postalCode! + " "
                    }

                    print(addressString)
                }
            }
        }
```

**Output:**

> L-30, 2nd A Main Road, HSR Layout, Bengaluru, Karnataka, India, 560102

Comment: Thanks you sir..i tired your answer this is also working fine...future i think i have to use your answer...

Comment: @GowthamanM Great that worked for you. Why you have accepted other answer then? as you said you are going to use my answer in future.

Comment: @GowthamanM You should accept future proof code not simple one as you said you are going to use my code in future. Anyway both answer are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate
    let objLocation = CLLocation(latitude: locValue.latitude, longitude: locValue.longitude)
    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(objLocation) { (placemarksArray, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("Reverse geocoder failed with error" + (error?.localizedDescription)!)
            return
        }
        if (placemarksArray?.count)! > 0 {
            let objPlacemark = placemarksArray?[0]
            self.generateAddress(objPlacemark: objPlacemark!)
            self.locationManager?.stopUpdatingLocation()
            self.locationManager = nil
        }
        else {
            print("Problem with the data received from geocoder")
        }
    }
}
```

Function Parsing placemark to string...

```
func generateAddress(objPlacemark : CLPlacemark) -> String {

    print("objPlacemark : \(objPlacemark.description)")
    var completeAddress = ""

    if objPlacemark.name != nil {
        completeAddress = String(describing: objPlacemark.name!)
    }

    if objPlacemark.thoroughfare != nil && (objPlacemark.name != objPlacemark.thoroughfare) {
        completeAddress = completeAddress + ", " + String(describing: objPlacemark.thoroughfare!)
    }

    if objPlacemark.subThoroughfare != nil {
        completeAddress = completeAddress + ", " + String(describing: objPlacemark.subThoroughfare!)
    }

    if objPlacemark.subLocality != nil {
        completeAddress = completeAddress + "," + String(describing: objPlacemark.subLocality!)
    }

    if objPlacemark.locality != nil {
        completeAddress = String(describing: objPlacemark.locality!)
    }

    if objPlacemark.postalCode != nil {
        completeAddress = completeAddress + "," + String(describing: objPlacemark.postalCode!)
    }

    if objPlacemark.administrativeArea != nil {
        completeAddress = completeAddress + "," +  String(describing: objPlacemark.administrativeArea!)
    }

    if objPlacemark.isoCountryCode != nil {
        completeAddress = completeAddress + "," + String(describing: objPlacemark.isoCountryCode!)
    }

    print("completeAddress : \(completeAddress)")
    return completeAddress
}
```

Comment: Please try adding your comments for downvote, since this is a Q&A site, everyone has the opportunity to improve. Thanks

Comment: @GowthamanM, the comment is meant for the person whomsoever has downvoted without any explanation.

Answer (score 0):

`CLGeocodeCompletionHandler` contains an array of `CLPlacemark`. You can access its properties such as `name, locality, isoCountryCode` etc to form a complete address!!