# Detecting which village you are in

Tags: swift, api, maps

I'm using swift and the google Maps API. I was curious if it was possible to detect which village I'm in? For example if I'm in New York City detect if I'm in east village based on my GPS coordinates.  Is there a way for the API to do this or is my best bet to run a serious of comparisons on the coordinates and if they all meet the users current coordinates then assume they are in this village?

Comment: Are you able to get current location's latitude, longitude?

Comment: Yes I have the current longitude and latitude

Comment: Than you can easily convert  current location's latitude, longitude to current Address/Area.

Comment: With Maps or Places API? I'm not really sure how I would do that.

Comment: Please see This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27735835/convert-coordinates-to-city-name It may be helped.

Comment: In the maps API is there a way to use the place id to get directions from current location to the place id?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CLGeocoder](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/clgeocoder) from [CoreLocation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation) framework to obtain information based on coordinates

```
let geocoder: CLGeocoder = CLGeocoder()
let location: CLLocation = // your location here

geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: { (placemarks: [CLPlacemark]?, error: Error?) -> (Void) in 
    if let placemarks = placemarks, !placemarks.isEmpty
    {
        if let city = placemarks[0].locality, let sublocality = placemarks[0].subLocality
        {
            print("You're in \(sublocality) at \(city)")
        }
    }
    else
    {
        print("No info related to your location")
    }
})
```

Comment: This is the right idea but not working for my needs. It tells you you're in Manhattan when using any coordinate in NYC when in reality I'd like to know if I'm in East Village, Tribeca, Lower Manhattan. Those types of sublocalitys but nothing seems to be able to handle that :/

Comment: Take a look at CLPlacemark properties and test with the different properties availables. 

Comment: I have. None ever tell you the village. Closest you can get is "Manhattan" which isn't wrong but it's not as specific as I'd like to get.